# what is the best way to get the pst file sizes

Tags: vbscript, outlook

Could someone please suggest the best way to grab the pst  file sizes and write them out to the same text file next to the pst path.

Could someone please suggest the best way to grab the pst  file sizes and write them out to the same text file next to the pst path.

```
Dim objNetworkSet, objFSO, objFolder, objShell, objTextFile, objFile, objWMISysEnv,ObjItem, objTextFileUNC
Dim strHomePath, strDirectory, strFile, strText, strComputerName,strDirectoryUNC,strFileUNC
dim colItems

On Error Resume Next

Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objNS = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
objNS.Logon "Mike", "" , False, True

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set wshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

' Setting file names
strDirectory = "C:\Export"
strFile = "\" & ObjNetwork.Username & "-" & ObjNetwork.ComputerName & "-PST-Files.txt"

' Check to see if the file already exists exists
If objFSO.FolderExists(strDirectory) Then
   Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strDirectory)
Else
   Set objFolder = objFSO.CreateFolder(strDirectory)
End If

If objFSO.FileExists(strDirectory & strFile) Then
   Set objFolder2 = objFSO.GetFolder(strDirectory)
Else
   Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strDirectory & strFile)
   objFile.Close
End If


' OpenTextFile Method needs a Const value
' ForAppending = 8 ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2
Const ForAppending = 8

' Opening text file
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strDirectory & strFile, ForAppending, True)

For Each objFolder2 In objNS.Folders

    objTextFile.WriteLine(GetPSTpath(objFolder2.StoreID))

     Next

 Function GetPSTPath(input)
     For i = 1 To Len(input) Step 2
         strSubString = Mid(input,i,2)    
        If Not strSubString = "00" Then strPath = strPath & ChrW("&H" & strSubString)
     Next

    Select Case True
         Case InStr(strPath,":\") > 0  
            GetPSTPath = Mid(strPath,InStr(strPath,":\")-1)
         Case InStr(strPath,"\\") > 0  
            GetPSTPath = Mid(strPath,InStr(strPath,"\\"))
     End Select
 End Function
```

Comment: I don't see PSTs anywhere in your code.

Comment: You are correct, I should have asked: Help size the objects found in the Outlook profile. The output file lists the objects like so.          C:\Users\mike\AppData\Local\KVS\Enterprise Vault\C1576C0719evs01.mdc
C:\My Outlook Data File(1).pst

Comment: I don't really understand your entire comment.  Can you please reword it and/or modify your question with the pertinent information?

Comment: The scrript is logging into the Outlook profile Mike                  Set objNS = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
objNS.Logon "Mike", "" , False, True                                  I am able to write the objects found in this profile to a text file .pst .mdc etc but need the size of these objects to be written to the text file as-well.

Comment: `Dir /a/s c:\*.pst > "%userprofile%\desktop\pstpaths.txt"` at command prompt will give you a list.

Comment: `@for /r "c:\" %A in (*.pst) do @echo %~nxA %~dpA > "%userprofile%\desktop\pstpaths.txt"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help and suggestions. I came up with the following which grabs the users default Outlook profile launches Outlook, verifies the attached PSTs then outs to file, including username, PST location and size. The .MDC files are excluded which relate to Enterprise Vault local cache.

```
Dim objNetworkSet, objFSO, objFolder, objShell, objTextFile, objFile, objWMISysEnv,ObjItem, objTextFileUNC
Dim strHomePath, strDirectory, strFile, strText, strComputerName,strDirectoryUNC,strFileUNC
dim colItems

'On Error Resume Next

Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objNS = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set WSHShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

DefaultOutlookProfile = WSHShell.RegRead("HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows Messaging Subsystem\Profiles\DefaultProfile")
'MsgBox("DefaultOutlookProfile: " & DefaultOutlookProfile)
objNS.Logon DefaultOutlookProfile, "", False, True

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

' Setting file names
strDirectory = "\\NetworkShare\pstlog\"
strFile = ObjNetwork.Username & "-" & ObjNetwork.ComputerName & "-PST-Files.txt"

' Check to see if the file already exists exists
If objFSO.FolderExists(strDirectory) Then
   Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strDirectory)
Else
   Set objFolder = objFSO.CreateFolder(strDirectory)
End If

If objFSO.FileExists(strDirectory & strFile) Then
   Set objFolder2 = objFSO.GetFolder(strDirectory)
Else
   Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(strDirectory & strFile)
   objFile.Close
End If


' OpenTextFile Method needs a Const value
' ForAppending = 8 ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2
Const ForWriting = 2

' Opening text file
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strDirectory & strFile, ForWriting, True)

For Each strNS In objNS.Folders

    'objTextFile.WriteLine(GetPSTpath(strNS.StoreID))
    strPath2 = GetPSTpath(strNS.StoreID)
    'MsgBox("strPath2: " & strPath2)

    If Not strPath2 = "" And Not Right(strPath2, 4) = ".mdc" Then
        ' Get the file's size...
        intSize = FormatNumber((objFSO.GetFile(strPath2).Size/1048576), 2) & " MB"
        'intSize = intSize/1024 & " MB"

        ' Write both pieces of information to the output file...
        objTextFile.WriteLine(ObjNetwork.Username & ", " & strPath2 & ", " & intSize)
    End If
Next

Public Function GetPSTPath(input)
     For i = 1 To Len(input) Step 2
         strSubString = Mid(input,i,2)    
        If Not strSubString = "00" Then strPath = strPath & ChrW("&H" & strSubString)
     Next

    Select Case True
         Case InStr(strPath,":\") > 0  
            GetPSTPath = Mid(strPath,InStr(strPath,":\")-1)
         Case InStr(strPath,"\\") > 0  
            GetPSTPath = Mid(strPath,InStr(strPath,"\\"))
     End Select
 End Function



If err.number = vbEmpty then
  Else WScript.echo "VBScript Error: " & err.number
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `GetPSTPath()` function is returning the proper paths to the files you seek, and you just want to write the file sizes along with the file paths, you can do this:

```
For Each objFolder2 In objNS.Folders

    ' Get the file path...
    strPath = GetPSTpath(objFolder2.StoreID)

    ' Get the file's size...
    intSize = objFSO.GetFile(strPath).Size

    ' Write both pieces of information to the output file...
    objTextFile.WriteLine strPath & " = " & intSize

Next
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. The output to text file now only displays the .mdc file, the .pst files are missing. Also could you please help with converting the file size output to KB.

Comment: `Size` returns the size of the file in bytes. To convert to KB, you can just divide by 1024 (2^10). The change above shouldn't have affected _which_ files are written. We're still iterating the `objNS.Folders` collection, like you were doing originally.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I would have thought the same reference iterating the odjNS.Folders but it only displays one line, the .mdc file. I changed the following GetPSTPath = Mid(strPath,InStr(strPath,":\")-1) to GetPSTPath = Mid(strPath,InStr(strPath,":\")+1) then all the files display in the text file but the beginning of the path is truncated, no C: etc.